# How to end the session in spring 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session

I am using `@SessionAttributes` in spring, but I don't know how to end the session, I tried the below code but I am getting error, Please give me some example.

Thanks.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/LogoutAction")
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Resource res = new ClassPathResource("spring-context.xml");
    BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.invalidate();
    return "Login";
}
```

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Please post a stacktrace

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think the common problem when using `@SessionAttributes` is after you invalidate your current session, Spring MVC attach the model attributes back into the **new session** -- hence causing the impression it never invalidates

You can check the value of JSESSIONID before & after you invalidate it. You will get a brand new JSESSIONID, yet previous model attributes are attached straight into the new session

I found myself having to do this to wipe a model attribute of name "counter" from session after invalidating it

```
@RequestMapping(value="/invalidate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String invalidate(HttpSession session, Model model) {
  session.invalidate();
  if(model.containsAttribute("counter")) model.asMap().remove("counter");
  return "redirect:/counter";
}
```

If you have plenty attributes, ofcourse you can try wiping everything off using

```
model.asMap().clear();
```

But in my opinion better approach is to invalidate using a different controller that doesn't have `@SessionAttribute` on it. Hence whatever model attributes other controllers have won't be attached straight into the new session. Eg:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/logout")
public class LogoutController {

  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String logout(HttpSession session) {
    session.invalidate();
    return "redirect:/login";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a valuable answer

Answer (score 0):

This also should work (similar to what was purposed by gerrytan... and some years late)... suppose that your @SessionAttributes saves the "stuff" object that you create under a @ModelAtributte method:

```
@ModelAttribute("patient")
public Patient newPatient() {
    return new Patient();
}
/*
     other methods to do stuffs...
*/

@RequestMapping(value = "/logout")
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request, Model m) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
    m.addAttribute("patient", newStuff());
    return "redirect:/login"; 
}
```

So basically you capture the model send and you set a new object (of the type stored in the @SessionAtributte) and voilà... the SessionAttribute is still there but empty...

might be not the cleanest solution (i'm noob) but works in my local project)