# How to stay logged out after pressing back button in jsp (Spring MVC)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, servlets

This is my jsp page

in header I have put this

```html
<head>
<META Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<META Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<META Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
</head>
<body>
        <a href="logout">LogOut</a></li>
        <input type="hidden" id="fullname" name="fullname" value="${fullname}" >
</body>
```

here is my controller method

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView logout(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response, String fullname) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.removeAttribute(fullname);
        session.invalidate();
        mav.addObject("logout", true);
        mav.setViewName("Home2");
        return mav;
    }
```

but after pressing the back button, I again get redirected to the logged in page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to end the session in spring 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205841/how-to-end-the-session-in-spring-3)

Comment: Please use the session invalidate

Comment: @saifali I have used session.invaldiate in my controller method,

Comment: have session check in other controller or make a filter to check the paths to be session handeled

Answer (score 0):

just add,

```
if (session.getAttribute(fullname) == null) {
    return mav;
}
```